# Kohana Log - write error

Tags: php, kohana

I'm working with a site build on kohana 3, actually I'm starting to use kohana.
I  want to use a simple logging for errors.
I get errors in logs dir from app path on different things and I try to add one of my own and get into an error.

I do like this:

```
Kohana::$log->add('error', 'Could not locate user');
Kohana::$log->write();
```

After the last line I get into this error:

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined index: error

SYSPATH\classes\kohana\log\file.php [ 91 ]

86 
87      foreach ($messages as $message)
88      {
89          // Write each message into the log file
90          // Format: time --- level: body
91          file_put_contents($filename, PHP_EOL.$message['time'].' --- '.$this->_log_levels[$message['level']].': '.$message['body'], FILE_APPEND);
92      }
93  }
94 
95 } // End Kohana_Log_File
SYSPATH\classes\kohana\log\file.php [ 91 ] » Kohana_Core::error_handler(arguments)

SYSPATH\classes\kohana\log.php [ 184 ] » Kohana_Log_File->write(arguments)

APPPATH\classes\controller\main.php [ 23 ] » Kohana_Log->write()

{PHP internal call} » Controller_Main->action_index()

SYSPATH\classes\kohana\request\client\internal.php [ 118 ] » ReflectionMethod->invoke(arguments)

SYSPATH\classes\kohana\request\client.php [ 64 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(arguments)

SYSPATH\classes\kohana\request.php [ 1138 ] » Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)

DOCROOT\index.php [ 109 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

What is wrong with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just use Log constants for message types, e.g.

`Kohana::$log->add(Log::ERROR, 'Could not locate user');`

because these reflect error types in PHP.

P.S. there's no need to call Log::write(), it's done automatically on shutdown.